# Mixed GLMM Model - Issues with using weights (Using R package 'lme4'

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to implement a mixed and weighted logistic regression model using the glmer function from the package 'lme4' in R. This is how my function looks

```
mixed <- glmer(Category ~ Parameter + (1|StudyNo), 
               family = binomial(logit), 
               dataforreg, 
               weights = dataforreg$Weight)
```

This is the error I receive when I execute the above line of code, I understand the warning message about non-integer, but I don't understand the source of the error.

> Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev
>   = compDev, : (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate In addition: Warning message: In
>   eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer #successes in a binomial
>   glm!

However, when i remove the weights, the model works fine.
Can anyone please guide me on solving the error?

Thanks in advance